# We received/had received a letter

Tags: sentence, past-tense

I want to acknowledge on receipt of a letter.

Which one is correct

> "we received" or "we had received"?

And please explain the usages too.
Thanks

Comment: Please visit [ell.se] -- Good Luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In verb tenses "we received" is simple past "we had received" is past perfect.

The simple past is used to describe actions and/or events that are now completed and no longer true in the present.

The past perfect describes completed events that took place in the past before another past event.

Comment: So I have to use "had received" as we actually received it on last friday, Correct?

Comment: You may use both to express past event, it depends on your sentence. For example: "We had received the parcel last Friday when my boss asked about it".

Comment: It shows that the action "had received" happened before another past action "asked".

Comment: Hello, Ann. This question is not suitable for ELU, as I think you would agree if you read the advice at the Help Center. One reason is that it's been addressed here before.